# when listing docker images using the gcloud cli, the results seem not sorted unless --sort-by is the last argument

Tags: google-cloud-sdk, gcloud-cli

I am executing the following command:

```bash
gcloud artifacts docker images list ${REPO} --quiet --format="get(package)" --limit=1 --sort-by=~update_time
```

This indeed gives me the correct package name of the last updated image. However, when I change the order of the arguments like so:

```bash
gcloud artifacts docker images list ${REPO} --quiet --sort-by=~update_time --format="get(package)" --limit=1
```

Which; to me; is a more natural order, I get a wrong result (not the last updated image).

My question: is this a bug, intended behaviour or according to specifications? I have not been able to find any documentation about this.

Thank you very much for your time.

Sacha

I permuted several executes and only with `--sort-by=` as last argument does it seem to be respected